# How to set data for floating point texture?

Tags: webgl

I’m trying to set numeric data to a texture, I’d like to store one unclamped 32 bit float in a 4 byte pixel, I’m using JavaScript for WebGL2, here is my current code:

```js
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA32F;
  const width = 3;
  const height = 2;
  const border = 0;
  const format = gl.RGBA;
  const type = gl.FLOAT;
  const data = new Float32Array([ ... 24 values ...]);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, format, type, data);
```

It was my understanding that this setup should do the trick but it only works if I set 24 values in the array, i.e. 4 clamped values for each pixel’s RGBA channel individually.

If I set 6 values, I get an error ‘ArrayBufferView not big enough for request’, how do I make it work?

Comment: I think it's one 32-bit float per color component. That would be 4 floats (16 bytes) per pixel. Have you tried `new Float32Array(96);`?

Comment: so what is the format for storing 32 bit float (like a standard single precision ieee754 one) in a 4 byte pixel?

Comment: I don't know, but it seems you want R32F. Maybe this will help: https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html

Comment: yes, you're right, thank you!